# Find the relationship among adjusted 3-pointer (not parameter, but formula like Pythagenport, Pythagenpat), goals scored and goals allowed in football

Tags: statistics, optimization, regression, functional-inequalities, linear-pde

I was seeking a formula to relate goals scored and goals allowed to points in [association football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_points_for_a_win).

> In association football, three points are awarded to the team winning a match, with no points awarded to the losing team. If the game is drawn, each team receives one point.

Firstly, I worked with points percentage — points divided by available points, which I set to the number of matches multiplied by adjusted 3-pointer. The general form was:
$${\rm points}\,{\rm percentage}= \frac{{\rm goals}\,{\rm scored}^{\mathcal{A}}}{{\rm goals}\,{\rm scored}^{\mathcal{A}}+ {\rm goals}\,{\rm allowed}^{\mathcal{B}}}$$
*The league tables' total points percentage is almost sure not an integer*.
This is [Pythagorean expectation](http://www.hockeyanalytics.com/Research_files/DayaratnaMiller_HockeyFinal.pdf) (only for wins/losses, not for draws) with two forced different exponents! Football presents a Pythagorean challenge because about a quarter of its matches end in draws (*related to [trimean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimean) ? [no](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4502888/822157).), worth one point each in the league tables. Because wins are worth three points, the most accurate Pythagorean analyses overestimate most teams’ points totals, as football analyst Howard Hamilton [has found](https://www.soccermetrics.net/soccer-pythagorean-theory/why-the-baseball-pythagorean-doesnt-work-for-soccer).
I call adjusted 3-pointer instead of three because how many average points each team receives are not same. I want to achieve 'reasonable' relationship among adjusted 3-pointer (not parameter, but formula like [Pythagenport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_expectation#Empirical_origin), [Pythagenpat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_expectation#Empirical_origin)), goals scored and goals allowed for each team:
$${\rm points}_{predicted}= {\rm points}\,{\rm percentage}\cdot{\rm adjusted}\,3{\rm -pointer}$$
*If you treat adjusted 3-pointer as parameter*:
Here is the win estimator (Python Code)

```
# 17 Th12 '12
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XwKs4Do3x95hGTnzgwJWJqCXa4Zqns74bXPwXFFv3IE

import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
x=np.array([33,43,28,26,28,30,26,24,15,21,23,28,19,18,19,22,15,19,18,15])
y=np.array([15,24,17,16,21,25,22,21,13,20,23,29,25,24,26,32,24,31,32,30])
z=np.array([36,42,29,24,27,29,23,27,24,23,22,20,25,16,17,15,18, 9,15,10])
N=np.array([17,17,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,16,17,16,17,17])
pred=lambda w: (x**w[0]/(x**w[0]+y**w[1]))*(2+1/(w[2]**2+1))*N
w,_=scipy.optimize.leastsq(lambda w: (z-pred(w)),(1,1,.0009332150))
w
```

```
print(w[0])
print(w[1])
print(2+1/(w[2]**2+1))
```

Hence, we obtain

```
A=1.5981207542056926
B=1.6055482567109685
adjusted 3-pointer=2.742957368624336
```

As you can see, I choose ${\rm adjusted}\,3{\rm -pointer}= 2+ 1/(w^{2}+ 1)\in\left ( 2, 3 \right )$ because the average total points of football matches is on this interval. And ${\rm adjusted}\,3{\rm -pointer}\lessapprox 2.75$ is scientific* (noted above). On the other side, $w> {\rm Best}\,w\Rightarrow 2\lessapprox{\rm adjusted}\,3{\rm -pointer}$ leads to many under-performing teams, despite of well RMSE, I still want adjusted 3-pointer as a formula ([function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagenpat)), but parameter. I have tried to turning that into an ODE (In fact, a PDE.) but unsuccessfully. I need your help to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply ordinary least squares method in your case and to try and answer your questions afterwards, I first derive two types of equations:

**1. Linear observation equations**.
Denote the expected points percentage by $p$, total goals scored by $TGS$, total goals allowed by $TGA$, and the corresponding exponents by $\alpha$, $\beta$ respectively. Then your first formula becomes
\begin{equation}
p = \frac{\text{TGS}^{\alpha}}{\text{TGS}^{\alpha} + \text{TGA}^{\beta}}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

We can derive a model that is linear in exponents $\alpha, \beta$ in the following way. First, notice that
$$
\frac{p}{1-p} = \frac{\text{TGS}^{\alpha}}{\text{TGA}^{\beta}}
$$
Taking the logarithm
$$
\log{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)} = \alpha \cdot \log{\left(\text{TGS}\right)} - \beta \cdot \log{\left(\text{TGA}\right)}
$$
Now, if we introduce
$$
y := \log{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)} \qquad
x_1 := \log{\left(\text{TGS}\right)} \qquad
x_2 := \log{\left(\text{TGA}\right)} 
$$
we arrive at a simple linear relationship:
$$
y = \alpha \cdot x_1 - \beta \cdot x_2
$$
The dependent variable $y$ is called a *response* and independent variables $x_1, x_2$ are known as *regressors*.

Given some data $y_{i}$, $x_{i1}$, $x_{i2}$, $i = 1, \dots n$, we can write a linear model in parameters $\alpha, \beta$ as
\begin{equation}
y_i = \alpha \cdot x_{i1} - \beta \cdot x_{i2} + \varepsilon_{i}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Under assumptions that $\varepsilon$ has mean $0$ and $\varepsilon \perp x_{1}, x_{2}$, we can use ordinary least squares (OLS) in order to find the estimates $\widehat{\alpha}$ and $\widehat{\beta}$. This gives us the estimate of $y_{i}$ as
$$
\widehat{y_{i}} = \widehat{\alpha} \cdot x_{i1} - \widehat{\beta} \cdot x_{i2}
$$

We can then also express the estimate for $p_{i}$ as
\begin{equation}
\widehat{p_{i}} = \frac{1}{1 + \exp{\left(-\widehat{y_{i}}\right)}}
\end{equation}

Finally, the mean squared error (MSE) of an estimator of $p$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\text{MSE} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left( 
p_{i} - \widehat{p_{i}}
\right)^{2}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}
And taking the square root of the MSE yields the root mean squared error (RMSE).

**2. Nonlinear observation equations**.
If we introduce a new parameter $\gamma$ and define *adjusted 3-pointer* as a real valued function $h(\gamma)$. For example, as you defined in your question
\begin{equation}
h(\gamma) = 2 + \frac{1}{1 + \gamma^{2}}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}
then the formula (1) becomes:
\begin{equation}
p = \frac{TGS^{\alpha}}{TGS^{\alpha} + TGA^{\beta}} \cdot h(\gamma)
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

The response $y = \log{\left( p / (1 - p) \right)}$ is now some non-linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of parameters $\pmb{w} := [\alpha, \beta, \gamma]^{T}$. We can again derive a model that is linear in parameters $\pmb{w}$ in the following way.

Let $\Delta y = f(\pmb{w}) - f(\pmb{w_0})$ and $\nabla f (\pmb{w_{0}})$ a vector of partial derivatives $\left[
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \alpha}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma} \right]^T$ evaluated at $\pmb{w_0} = [\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0]^T$. Linearization of $y = f(\pmb{w})$ yields the linear model in $\Delta \pmb{w} = \pmb{w} - \pmb{w_0}$:
\begin{equation}
\Delta y = \nabla f (\pmb{w_{0}})^T \Delta \pmb{w} + \varepsilon
\tag{6}
\end{equation}

Again, under assumptions that $\varepsilon$ has mean $0$ and $\pmb{\varepsilon} \perp \pmb{w}$, we can use ordinary least squares (OLS) to find the estimate $\widehat{ \Delta \pmb{w}}$, and use it to get $\widehat{\pmb{w}} = \pmb{w_0} + \widehat{ \Delta \pmb{w}}$.

**Iterative scheme.** To get a final estimate $\widehat{\pmb{w}}$, start at some initial guess $\pmb{w_0} = [\alpha_0, \beta_0, \gamma_0]^T$. Solve (6) using OLS to get an update $\Delta\widehat{\pmb{w}}$ and use it to get the new estimate:
$$
\widehat{\pmb{w_{1}}} = \pmb{w_{0}} + \Delta\widehat{\pmb{w}}
$$
Set $\pmb{w_{0}} \leftarrow \pmb{w_{1}}$ and repeat, until $\newcommand{\norm}[1] {\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}\norm{\widehat{ \Delta \pmb{w} }}_{2}$ becomes sufficiently small.

---

**Now, to try and answer your questions.** Yes, using a model based on nonlinear observation equations derived from (5), can lead to an estimator $\widehat{p}$ with a better RMSE, since a more complex model with more parameters can better fit the data. But, I don't understand what you mean by:

> On the other side, $w> {\rm Best}\,w\Rightarrow 2\lessapprox{\rm adjusted}\,3{\rm -pointer}$ leads to many under-performing teams

This can mean that $\widehat{p}$ is a biased estimator of the expected points percentage $p$. To get an unbiased estimator $\widehat{p}$ using OLS, the assumptions of OLS must be satisfied. Check that the estimated residuals $\widehat{\varepsilon}_i = y_i - \widehat{y_i}$ have mean $0$ and are not correlated with regressors $x_i$. Otherwise the iterative scheme of updates $\Delta\widehat{\pmb{w}}$ is not valid. When using some package, e.g. `scipy.optimize`, check if `leastsq` returns any warnings. Or you can try implementing the iterative scheme yourself and check the assumptions. If assumptions are not satisfied, you have to choose a different model. Also, a more complex model can easily overfit the data, so cross-validation is usually used to validate the results.

> I have tried to turning that into an ODE (In fact, a PDE.) but unsuccessfully. I need your help to find it.

To model the points percentage $p$ with a PDE, you need to describe the relation between partial derivatives of $p$ with respect to the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. From your description of $p$, I don't see that it has to satisfy some PDE.

**Final remarks.**

- If you are looking for this relationship for $p$ in a data driven way, what your question points to, this is a standard problem in machine learning. But the result will not be some simple formula, but a fitted model.
- For example, you can fit a neural network to find the relationship you are looking for. Since even a single hidden layer network can approximate any continuous function. Again, to not overfit, validate the result, for example by using cross-validation.
- But, when given little amount of data, avoid fitting a more complex model. To model rare events such as goals, the Poisson distribution is typically used.
- Finding an analytical expression that matches data from an unknown function is in principle NP-hard. Instead, any polynomial and rational function modeling is typically knowledge-driven.
- This means that you have to come up with a simple formula for the relationship you are looking for based on the nature of the problem and then find the values of parameters using some optimization technique.

Comment: What style! This is the answer I have waited for a long long time. Thanks a real lot!

Comment: Thank you, I am happy to hear that!

Comment: Would you like to help me_ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4502888/822157 ? I have protected it for a long time.